# Exportar excel a partir de consulta postgres en php

Tags: php, excel

necesito exportar el resultado de 
una consulta que estoy imprimiendo en una tabla 
en php, 
Actualmente tengo dos tablas (consultas) en mi 
página que se muestran a la par pero necesito 
exportar a un archivo excel el resultado de 
una.

esta es mi consulta

```
<form type="submit" method="post" role="form- 
horizontal" id="form-fil"> 
<div class="form-group"> 

<div class="col-sm-2" id="tittle"> 

<h1>Formulario</h1> 

<select class="form-control" 
name="selRez" id="selRez" > 

<?php 


$query="select * from tabla1 where clave = $var;"; 

$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query  failed: ' . pg_last_error()); 

$rows = pg_num_rows ($result); 

$i = pg_num_fields($result); 

//Construyo mi tabla    

while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result)){ 

if ($line[0] <> "") { 

echo "<option value='$line[0]' >$line[1] 
</option>"; 

}else{ 

echo"<option >&nbsp;</option>"; 

} 

} 

?> 

</select> 

</div> 

</div>  

</form>
```

quisiera agregar la funcionalidad que les comento 
en esta parte del codigo

```
<td aling= "right" ><a href="excelTabla.php" target"_blank" style="display:inline"><img src="./img/excelIcon.png"</a></td>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, se los agradezco de 
antemano

Comment: Implementa la librería phpExcel y de esa manera trabajas con los funcionalidades que te brinda. Sldos.

Comment: Ya estuve leyendo acerca de la librería pero encuentro que la manejan con consultas mysql, nada de postgres :( y la verdad no sé como convierto ese código a que me se útil para postgres

Comment: Mira la sig. url, sldos: http://www.ingeografos.com.pe/2015/02/postgresql-y-php.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez a alguien le sirva, aquí os dejo un código que sirve exportar nuestra consulta a excel con el motor de base de datos postgres

```
<?php
include_once "miBDConection.php";
session_start();
//mi query
    $select="select * from table;";

    $export = pg_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . pg_error( ) );
    $fields = pg_num_fields ( $export );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
    {
        $header .= pg_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
    }

    while( $row = pg_fetch_row( $export ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach( $row as $value )
        {
            if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
            {
                $value = "\t";
            }
            else
            {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n" ;
    }
    $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );



    if ( $data == "" )
    {
        $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";
    }
    $filename = "reporte_rezagoZAP-" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\n$data";
?>
```

**Espero les sirva, saludos**

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar la libreria phpExcel con la finalidad de generar interaccion con excel, ya sea para generar archivos excel como te enuncio a continuacion:

```
/*
aquí generas tu consulta y almacenas en un dataSet con el fin de generar una variable php que almacene lo que requieres... puedes iterar con un array que `introducir el código aquí`armes...
*/

    require_once('../_lib/libraries/sys/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php');

    // Crea un nuevo objeto PHPExcel
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', {dsExample[0][0]});    
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B1', 'column B');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C1', 'column C');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D1', 'Column D');    
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E1', 'Column E');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('F1', 'Column F');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('G1', 'Column G');
    ob_end_clean();

    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xlsx"');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    ob_end_clean();

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: tengo una duda y disculpe si soy tan persistente, recién estoy incursionando en la programación, pero, el mecanismo seria así? Este código que me indicas guardarlo en un archivo, (reporteExcel.php) y después llamarlo aquí: <td aling= "right" ><a href="reporteExcel.php" target"_blank" style="display:inline"><img src="./img/excelIcon.png"</a></td>

Comment: La idea es que en el formulario direccionas al excel y posteriormente en el archivo destino generas la dinámica con la librería, instanciando el obj de PHPExcel, donde coloco "php://output" lo que hace es que cuando direccionas a esa pagina se genera un excel y te lo descarga en tu navegador... te menciono una librería para no hacer manual el proceso del excel, así puedes posteriormente haces mas cosas al haberla implementado. no seria necesario el target blank ya que el excel lo que hace es descargarte el archivo donde sea que coloques su href. Sldos