# Como crear un reporte en excel en php sin uso de librerias

Tags: php

¿Como exporto un reporte en excel con sus filas y columnas desde php sin el uso de librerias externas se puede hacer?

Answer (score 5):

si efectivamente puedes crear el excel manual de la siguiente manera:

```
<?PHP
  namespace Chirp;

  // Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  $data = array(
    array("firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => 25),
    array("firstname" => "Amanda", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 18),
    array("firstname" => "James", "lastname" => "Brown", "age" => 31),
    array("firstname" => "Patricia", "lastname" => "Williams", "age" => 7),
    array("firstname" => "Michael", "lastname" => "Davis", "age" => 43),
    array("firstname" => "Sarah", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 24),
    array("firstname" => "Patrick", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 27)
  );

  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }

  // file name for download
  $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

  $flag = false;
  foreach($data as $row) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
  }

  exit;
?>
```

Bibliografia: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/

Es importante tener en cuenta que el uso manual implica que cualquier cambio de estilo y demás va a ser manual y por tanto personalmente prefiero usar librerías como phpExcel, pero para dar respuesta a tu inquietud si es posible como te muestro en el ejemplo y la bibliografía respectivas...

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Jose una pregunta? El excel tambien se podria generar de la misma manera pero con extension .xlsx ?

Comment: Buen día Jhon, revisando en la documentación para hacer un documento excel 2007 en adelante se usa el siguiente Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

te dejo la URL de la pregunta donde encuentro la rpta. Saludos. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123912/mime-type-for-excel-2007

Comment: John me gustaria preguntar pq no usas una libreria... phpExcel es una buena opcion ya que tiene documentacion y en general tiene un uso simple... y de igual forma te dejo un enlace de otra libreria un poco mas ligera, saludos. http://www.zedwood.com/article/php-xlsx-spreadsheet-creator

Comment: Iba a usar la libreria phpExcel es super genial, pero me causaba errores al momento del uso de namespace y MVC en mi app

Comment: Entiendo Jhon... a continuación te relaciono una URL donde comparto la implementación de phpExcel, espero te sea de utilidad, saludos. 

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142939/exportar-excel-a-partir-de-consulta-postgres-en-php/142951#142951